# Switch HLS video stream to audio when app goes in background

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, mpmovieplayer

I am using HTTP Live Streaming Protocol to stream video and audio on demand in my app. The video playlist (m3u8 file) has an audio only version which is playing when the connection is very poor. When the app goes in background I want to play the audio of the video. Is there a way to achieve this, like forcing the MPMoviePlayer to switch to audio only, and then when they open the app to switch to a video version.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution?